# Strange thing happening with me in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, refs

So I Have this loop of inputs(code below :)). So basically I'm trying to get every input in that loop by a unique ref like its explained in Vue3 documentations => [Here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#usage-inside-v-for)

I have this Array `inputs` where I'm saving all inputs like documentations suggest. what I want to achieve here is getting the last value. But I'm facing a strange issue that's why I'm here.
So when I try to `console.log` the last value of that array I get the before last one not the last(I'll explain with image for more comprehension).and when I `console.log` the `inputs` array I can see that it contains the last value but I cant get it with all methods I tried:

```
console.log(inputs.value[inputs.value.length-1])
console.log(inputs.value.at(-1))
```

html code:

```
<n-card v-for="(item, index) in counter" :key="index" title="Card">
   <div v-if="item.val == 'radio'">
    <div class="row" v-for="(i, index) in item.items" :key="index">
          <div class="col-1">
            <n-icon size="25">
              <radio-icon></radio-icon>
            </n-icon>
          </div>
          <div class="col-10">
            <n-input
              :ref="el => {if (el) inputs[index] = el}"
              @focus="$event.target.select()"
              v-model:value="i.name"
              placeholder="taper ici"
              >
            </n-input>
          </div>
          <div class="col-1">
            <n-button v-if="item.items.length > 1"
              @click="deleteOption(item.id, i.id)"
            >
              <n-icon size="20">
                <delete-icon />
              </n-icon>
            </n-button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </n-card>
```

script:

```
const Add = id => {
  const found = counter.value.find(item => item.id === id)
  if (found.items.length > 0){
    let lastValue = found.items[found.items.length-1].inc
    lastValue++
    found.items.push(
      {
        id: new Date().valueOf(),
        name: `option ${lastValue}`,
        inc: lastValue
      }
    )
    inputs.value[inputs.value.length-1].focus()
    console.log(inputs.value[inputs.value.length-1])// here I get before last value
    console.log(inputs.value.at(-1))// here I get before last value
    console.log(inputs.value)//here I get all inputs including last one
  }
  else {
    let lastValue = 1
    found.items.push(
      {
        id: new Date().valueOf(),
        name: `option ${lastValue}`,
        inc: lastValue
      }
    )
  }
}
```

[image: first Console.log]

[image: second console.log]

[image: third console.log]

pls guys help and sorry for my bad English.
I'll push the code in github. if anyone wanna see the full code and wants to help. I'll appreciate any help. Its driving me crazy.

Comment: What do you need the `:ref` for? Your `for` loop loops over `item.items`, not `inputs`. Is it a typo or is your example code here wrong?

Comment: I made that example for simplicity

Comment: Okay please update the real code then in the question, otherwise it is misleading as a typo. Thanks.

Comment: can I put a link for u to see full code in github?

Comment: The code in GitHub is useless here. This is not a forum. This is a question/answer database. The more long-lasting your question is, the more it can help others. Please post all relevant code here.

Comment: okii but its very long tho

Comment: Who wants to debug that then for you? Reduce your problem to the relevant parts. See [How to create a minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I did it pls take a look again.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But your code still says `v-for="(i, index) in item.items"`. Your `console.log` calls test `inputs.value` instead. Are you looping the correct values?

Comment: theres an input down the loop **:ref="el => {if (el) inputs[index] = el}"**
check docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is, that there is no "re-render" between setting the data and trying to search it in the "ui"(inputs) list. Try to add `await nextTick()`after your `found.items.push`. Then vue can re-render and the `v-for`will add the item to `inputs`.